# Why I'm getting AttributeError?

Tags: python, git-submodules

I'm making an application with the Yo api in python ( https://github.com/parthanium/YoPy ) and I'm getting a very strange error.

So, I've cloned the repo into my workspace, and I've created the following file (test.py) that works as expected when I run 'python test.py' :

```
import yopy

token = "secret"
username = "testUser"
link = "https://github.com/parthanium/YoPy"

yo = yopy.Yo(token)
print yo
print yo.number()
```

Now the problem:

I've a project that includes the previous project (Yo api in python) as a git submodule:

```
yo/
├── README.md
├── gitmodules
│   └── yopy
│       ├── LICENSE
│       ├── README.md
│       └── yopy.py
└── yo.py
```

the yo.py file has the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("gitmodules/yopy")
import yopy
import struct

token = "secret"
username = "testUser"
link = "https://github.com/parthanium/YoPy"

yo = yopy.Yo(token)
print yo
print dir(yo)
print yo.number()
```

and I get the following error output when running:

```
<yopy.Yo object at 0x10cc29190>
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_session', 'token', 'user', 'yo', 'yo_all']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yo.py", line 13, in <module>
    print yo.number()
AttributeError: 'Yo' object has no attribute 'number'
```

Why am I getting this error? The dir(yo) is outputing weird attributes like 'yo_all' and 'yo', 'user'...

Edit: 
Tried 'print yopy.**file**' and the result was https://gist.github.com/pedrorijo91/4fb4defe7a7c2d8a2fdc (thanks @abarnert)

Comment: What do you see if you run dir(yo.yo)?

Comment: @HackSaw I would get: ['__call__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__func__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'im_class', 'im_func', 'im_self']

Comment: Please check the indention for /gitmodules/yopy/yopy.py. It sounds weird I know, but I have encountered this scenario a few times.

Comment: Are you sure that what you have in `gitmodules/yopy` is the same thing that's at https://github.com/parthanium/YoPy?  Because what you're getting from `dir` doesn't seem like it could possibly have come from the file at https://github.com/parthanium/YoPy/blob/master/yopy.py. Maybe you have an old version, and he's changed the API since then?

Comment: @JimmyK but if it was indentation wouldn't the first scenario also fail?

Comment: Hold on… Do you have something _else_ that's _also_ named `yopy` somewhere on your `sys.path`? Like, say, right in the current directory? Because if so, `sys.path.append(…)` is going to put this new `yopy` that you wanted _after_ the old one that you didn't want. (Note that if you had a file named `yopy.py`, and deleted it, you may still have left behind `yopy.pyc`, and Python will still import that.)

Comment: Try adding a `print yopy.__file__` and see what it tells you.

Comment: @abarnert yeah, the files are updated..

Comment: In that case, you're not importing the file you think you are. You have something else called either `yopy.py` or `yopy.pyc`, or a directory named `yopy`, that's somewhere on` sys.path`, probably right there in the current working directory you're trying to run this from.

Comment: Wow, two totally different modules that happen to have the same name, and define a class with the same name and the same constructor, but otherwise aren't compatible at all. You really got unlucky here…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that you have something else named `yopy.py`, `yopy.pyc`, or `yopy` in your `sys.path`, most likely in the current working directory that you're trying to run this from. It may be an old version of the same library, or some test program that you wrote to test the library, or some different project that has the same name.

Now, your `sys.path.append("gitmodules/yopy")` does add the right directory to the importer search path—but it adds it at the *end*, not the *start*. So, if there's a `./yopy.py` and also a `./gitmodules/yopy/yopy.py`, it's the first one that Python's going to import.

You can see what got imported by doing a `print yopy.__file__`. Or, better, `import inspect` and then `print inspect.getsourcefile(yopy)`.

Assuming this is the problem, the fix is to get rid of the other thing with the conflicting name. (You *could* instead just change the `sys.path.append(…)` to `sys.path.insert(0, …)`, but having the other `yopy` around is just going to lead to more confusion…)

Comment: wow, that was weird ! If I use the sys.insert() it works nicely, but sys.append() fails. But I don't have any *.pyc files in my directory, so how can append() still fails?

Comment: @pedrorijo91: I don't understand. You must have printed out `__file__` or `getsourcefile` and gotten a path, or you couldn't have made the edit to your question that shows the contents of whatever's at that path. So how do you not know what the path is?

Comment: sorry, misunderstand your words! everything fine now ! thanks a lot